# Is there any exp_internal equivalent in Pexpect

Tags: expect, pexpect

I have recently started with pexpect and trying to learn it through the analogy with Tcl/Expect. Since I am come from the Tcl/Expect background, I believe there must be something like "exp_internal".

Can someone let me know what is equivalent of "exp_internal" of Tcl/Expect in pexpect terminology.

PS: exp_internal in Tcl/Expect prints all the log messages produced by the internal regex engine. It clearly shows what was the buffer received by the expect and what regular expression it matched or did't match.

**EDIT**

No answer seems to have existed back when the question was posted. I will just try to edit the question with hope that there now is an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such feature in pexpect